# Apache Beam : How to return multiple outputs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

In the below function. I want to return **important_col** variable as well.

```
class FormatInput(beam.DoFn):                          
         def process(self, element):                 
             """ Format the input to the desired shape"""                    
             df = pd.DataFrame([element], columns=element.keys())                       
             if 'reqd' in df.columns:
                 important_col= 'reqd'
             elif 'customer' in df.columns:
                 important_col= 'customer'
             elif 'phone' in df.columns:
                 important_col= 'phone'
             else:
                 raise ValueError(['Important columns not specified'])
             output = df.to_dict('records')
             return output

with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)) as p:
    clean_csv = (p 
    | 'Read input file' >>  beam.dataframe.io.read_csv('raw_data.csv'))
    
    to_process = clean_csv | 'pre-processing' >> beam.ParDo(FormatInput())
```

In the above pipeline, I want to return **Important_col** variable from the Format Input.

1. Once I have that variable, I want to **pass it as argument** to next step in pipeline
2. I also want to dump **to_process** to CSV file.

I tried the following but none of them worked.

1. converted to_process to to_dataframe and tried to_csv. I got error.
2. I also tried to dump pcollection to csv. I am not getting how to do that. I referred official apache beam documents, but I dont find any documents similar to my use case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Apache Beam Multiple Outputs & Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52075600/python-apache-beam-multiple-outputs-processing)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into `DoFn` -> `TaggedOutput` and `ParDo` -> `with_outputs`?
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/

Idea is to output mulitple tagged PCollection from your FormatInput method and then you can access  `to_process.main`, `to_process.important_col` etc in downstream pipeline.